# Что бы вы хотели знать про Stack Overflow?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Stack Overflow — весьма необычный проект со многих сторон. На мой взгляд, сообществу может быть интересна какая либо-информация о нем, например, про организацию серверов, архитектуру проекта, структуру компании и так далее. Я бы с удовольствием взялся подготовить серию докладов про Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange). Доклады планирую прочитать либо на [встречах сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), либо на тематических конференциях с дальнейшей публикацией записи в открытый доступ (надеюсь, с возможностью живой трансляцией и вопросами из [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), для тех, кто участвует удаленно).

**Пожалуйста, подскажите, что именно вам интересно? Что бы вы хотели знать о компании, сайте, сообществе?**

С учетом политики компании относительно информации «публично по умолчанию», что означает, что любая информация внутри компании может разглашаться, мне кажется, можно будет собрать серию действительно интересных презентаций.

Если вы видели выступление кого-либо из сотрудников компании на английском, но хотели бы услышать и обсудить его на русском, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь опубликовать вашу идею. Я постараюсь связаться с первоисточником и максимально вовлечь его в процесс подготовки доклада.

*Как опубликовать заявку?*

Уверен, в данном вопросе не стоит придерживаться какого-либо формата, но все же было бы здорово, если бы вы

- использовали новый ответ для каждой новой идеи;
- публиковали одну идею в одном ответе;
- в ответе указывали тип доклада (технический, менеджмет и т. д.);
- в ответе как можно более подробно описывали, что именно вы бы хотели видеть в докладе в формате: тема доклада и 3-7 тезисов доклада;
- запрашивали тему, которую можно рассказать в формате доклада (презентация до 30 минут и 15 минут на вопросы/ответы).

Comment: Мне (и я уверен не только мне) было бы очень увлекательно прочитать  про ваш HashCode также как это описал в своих статьях Nick Craver про StackOverflow. Ведь это тоже часть SO! Мне хотелось бы знать про использование железа, ПО и о том почему и как произошло преобразование в ruSO?

Comment: @Bharata Спасибо за предложение! Я [писал о причинах произошедшего на внешней платформе](https://vc.ru/story/11103-knowledge-network-stack-overflow).

Comment: Благо дарю за ссылку – увлекательно было почитать две статьи про ваш HashCode, в названии которых почему-то ни слова о нём. Вообще не умеют писать там названия! Я так понял, что мной предложенные статьи вы напишете? Ещё я вам писал **[здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3037/297453/#comment35130_3037)** (возможно вы не заметили).

Answer (score 10):

Мне (думаю и не только мне) было бы интересно послушать про техническую сторону системы. Особенно что касается главного английского сайта StackOverflow. У них огромная загруженность, тысячи вопросов в день, десятки тысяч ответов, уйма комментариев, голосов. При этом всё работает и многое обновляется в риалтайме, уведомления прилетают. При этом же доступна абсолютно любая статистика. Захотел посмотреть за что такой-то пользователь получил 200 баллов репутации 15 марта 2012 года — взял и посмотрел. Захотел глянуть, какое место занимал в недельном рейтинге репутации данный пользователь 1 января 2014 года — взял и посмотрел. Я уж не говорю про [публичный язык запросов](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), казалось бы заддосить должно быть легче лёгкого.

План лекции мог бы быть таким:

- Серверные технологии. Какие используются языки программирования, библиотеки, СУБД. Была ли в последние годы миграция с одних технологий на другие, чем она была вызвана.
- Топология хранения данных. Много ли серверов, как они распределены по функциям. Дублируются ли данные в географически разнесённых пунктах. Разделяются ли данные на активные и архивные (возможно, старые вопросы, к которым редко поступает запрос, постепенно мигрируют в другое хранилище). Еженедельные/месячные/квартальные рейтинги пользователей генерируются статически?
- Как пересчитывается репутация в сложных случаях (например, удаление пользователя)? Как я понимаю, движок хранит не просто текущее значение репутации, а способен полностью пересчитать ещё по серии предыдущих событий. Делается полный пересчёт или инкрементально?
- Как достигается консистентность данных. Скажем, свежий голос за вопрос одновременно влияет на количество голосов за данный вопрос, появляется в профиле спросившего и может привести к выдаче значка типа Nice Question. Также это влияет на репутацию спросившего и может привести к выдаче привелегии или значка. А если в это время кто-то другой выдал голос вниз или я почти сразу отменил свой голос? При этом голос ещё влияет на общее количество голосов (за день или общее, только за вопросы или за всё), выданных данным пользователем, появляется в его профиле и может привести к выдаче значка типа Vox Populi, или Electorate, или Civic Duty. Эти все данные находятся в одной базе или в разных? Могут ли они рассинхронизироваться? Какие технологии используются, чтобы этого избежать?
- Что стоит за data.stackexchange.com? Там собственный парсер запросов? Вряд ли это напрямую отдаётся в СУБД. Были ли случаи, когда запросы оттуда нагружали систему? Отфильтровываются ли опасные запросы?
- Клиент-серверный обмен: какие используются протоколы (там вроде на веб-сокетах многое, но я могу ошибаться), почему выбраны они.

Comment: Вот немного по теме вашего вопроса: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/154101. Но конечно доклад, на котором можно задать любой интересующий слушателя вопрос, гораздо интереснее.