# Stack Overflow: Аппаратное обеспечение 2016

Tags: поддержка

<sub>Перевод статьи [Stack Overflow: The Hardware - 2016 Edition](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/) [@Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver).</sub>

---

Кто обожает аппаратное обеспечение? Я… Если вы *не* любите «железо», я бы закрыл браузер на вашем месте.

Вы все еще здесь? Очень рад. Или у вас очень медленный браузер, и тогда вам надо задуматься об обновлении аппаратной части вашего компьютера.

Я много, *много* раз повторял: **[быстродействие важно](http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/)**. Ваш код настолько быстр, насколько позволяет ему аппаратное обеспечение, и поэтому «железо» имеет большое значение. Как и у любой другой платформы, у Stack Overflow архитектура организована в виде слоев. Аппаратное обеспечение для нас – основание, и то, что «железо» сосредоточено внутри компании, дает нам множество преимуществ, недоступных при ином развитии событий, например, при работе на серверах, принадлежащих третьим лицам. Однако в связи с этим мы несем прямые и косвенные издержки. Но моя публикация не об этом, [это сравнение я предоставлю позже](https://trello.com/c/4e6TOnA7/87-on-prem-vs-aws-azure-etc-why-the-cloud-isn-t-for-us). А пока я бы хотел привести подробный перечень нашей инфраструктуры – для ознакомления и сравнения, и дать фотографии серверов (иногда без корпусов). Без фотографий страница загружалась бы быстрее, но я ничего не мог с собой поделать.

В целом ряде публикациях этой серии я буду давать множество цифр и спецификаций. Когда я говорю «загрузка нашего SQL-сервера почти всегда составляет 5–10% CPU,» – великолепно. Но  5–10% *от чего*? Тут нам нужна точка отсчета. Этот список аппаратного обеспечения задуман как ответ на такие вопросы, а также представляет собой отправную точку для сравнения с другими платформами, их производительностью, мощностью и т. д.

### Как мы собираем «железо»

Отказ от ответственности: я делаю это не один. George Beech ([@GABeech](https://twitter.com/GABeech)) – мой основной «подельник» по составлению спецификаций АО. Мы скрупулезно подбираем необходимое оборудование для каждого сервера в зависимости от его предназначения. Мы не заказываем «железо» оптом, позже придумывая, куда применить ту или иную деталь. И у нас есть помощники: для того чтобы оптимально подобрать АО, нужно знать, с какими задачами ему придется справляться, поэтому мы работаем в связке с программистами и/или инженерами по надежности функционирования оборудования с других сайтов.

Также мы размышляем, что будет лучше для нашей системы. Сервер – не остров, и вопрос его соответствия общей архитектуре определенно достоин внимания.  Какие сервисы будут работать на платформе, использовать хранилище данных, системный журнал? Ценной также является возможность использования меньшего числа компонентов или, как минимум, меньшего набора вариантов одного и того же компонента в системе.

Создавая спецификации нашего «железа», мы рассматриваем мириады требований, которые помогают нам определиться, что нужно заказывать. Я никогда, на самом деле, не выписывал этот список на бумаге, сохраняя его в уме, но попробую:

- Речь идет о вертикальном или горизонтальном масштабировании? (Мы покупаем одну машину побольше или несколько машин поменьше?)

  - Насколько серьезный запас мощности нам нужен/для нас желателен? (Каковы необходимые запасы мощности, возможности преодоления отказа?)
- Хранение:

  - Будет ли этот сервер/приложение использовать диск? (Нужно ли нам, кроме жестких дисков, что-либо еще?)
  - Если нужно, в каком объеме? (Какая нужна пропускная способность? Сколько файлов малого размера? Понадобятся ли SSD?)
  - Если нужны SSD, какая предполагается нагрузка на запись? (Что мы имеем в виду: Intel S3500/3700s, P360x, P3700s?)

    - Какая мощность SSD нам нужна? (Должно ли это быть двухуровневое решение с HDD?)
    - Являются ли эти данные абсолютно транзитными? (Может быть, SSD без конденсаторов, которые обойдутся значительно дешевле, подойдут лучше?)
  - Будут ли расширяться требования к хранению данных?(Нам нужен 1U-сервер на 10 отсеков или 2U-сервер на 26 отсеков?)
  - Рассматриваем ли мы сценарий создания хранилища данных? (Нам нужны дисководы на 3.5"? Если так, емкостью 12 или 16 дисков на шасси 2U?)

    - Целесообразно ли выбрать компромиссный вариант хранения данных с использованием задней панели на 3.5”, ограничив предел обработки 120W TDP?
  - Нужен ли нам прямой доступ к дискам? (Нужно ли, чтобы контроллер поддерживал прямой доступ?)
- Память:

  - Сколько памяти потребуется? (Что мы *обязаны* купить?)
  - Как много памяти *сможет* использовать сервер? (Что *целесообразно* будет купить?)
  - Понадобится ли в будущем расширение памяти? (На какой конфигурации каналов памяти стоит остановиться?)
  - Легко ли организован в приложении доступ к памяти? (Нужно ли нам использовать максимальную тактовую частоту?)
  - Предусмотрен ли высокопараллельный доступ к памяти? (Хотим ли мы делить одно и то же пространство между несколькими DIMM?)
- CPU:

  - Какой тип обработки нас интересует? (Базовый или более мощный процессор?)
  - Допускает ли CPU параллельный доступ? (Нужно ли нам меньшее число более быстрых ядер или большее число более медленных?)
  - Какими способами мы этого добьемся? Не будет ли жесткой конкуренции между уровнями кэш-памяти L2/L3? (Нужен ли нам для работы огромный кэш уровня L3?)
- Будет ли работа, в основном, производиться одним ядром? (Нужна ли нам максимальная тактовая частота?)

  - Если так, сколько процессов будет происходить одновременно? (Какая мощность нам нужна?)
- Сеть:

  - Нужна ли нам дополнительная возможность сетевого подключения в 10Gb? (“Промежуточная” ли это машина, например, балансировщик нагрузки?)
  - Какие объемы балансировки нам нужны на буферах Tx/Rx? (Какое число ядер CPU лучше всего справляется с балансировкой этих объемов?)
- Избыточность:

  - Нужны ли нам также сервера в DR дата-центре?
  - Нам нужно то же количество серверов или допустима меньшая избыточность?
- Нужен ли нам силовой кабель? Нет. Не нужен.

Теперь посмотрим, какое аппаратное обеспечение обслуживает сайты в нашем нью-йоркском QTS дата-центре. Скажу по секрету: на самом деле, дата-центр находится в граничащем с Нью-Йорком штате Нью-Джерси, но это строго между нами. Почему мы называем этот центр нью-йоркским? Потому что не хотим переименовывать все наши нью-йоркские сервера. Далее в списке я укажу, где и в чем денверский дата-центр отличается от нью-йоркского в плане спецификаций и уровней избыточности.

### Сервера, на которых работают сайты Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange

Для всех спецификаций, которые будут приводиться ниже, справедливы следующие глобальные утверждения:

- Стандартные диски ОС не включены в перечень. Большинство серверов используют пару 250 или 500GB SATA HDDs для разделов, **всегда** в RAID 1. Время загрузки для нас неважно, *и даже если бы было важно*, на любом нашем физическом сервере оно почти не зависит от скорости дисков.
- Все сервера соединены двумя или более линиями по 10Gb связи в активный/активный [LACP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol).
- Все сервера работают на однофазном питании 208V (питание через 2 PSU от 2 PDU, с двумя резервными источниками).
- Все сервера в Нью-Йорке подключены к питанию с помощью отдельных ответвлений электросети — в отличие от серверов в Денвере (предпочтения инженеров на местах).
- Все сервера имеют как [iDRAC-соединение](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/3204.dell-remote-access-controller-drac-idrac) (через управляющую сеть), так и KVM-соединение.

#### Сеть

- 2 центральных коммутатора Cisco Nexus [5596UP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/nexus-5596up-switch/index.html) (96 SFP+ портов на 10 Gbps каждый)
- 10 Cisco Nexus [2232TM](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/nexus-2232tm-10ge-fabric-extender/index.html) расширителя Fabric Extender (**2 на стойку** — каждый имеет 32 BASE-T порта на 10Gbps + 8 SFP+ 10Gbps каналов)
- 2 межсетевых экрана Fortinet [800C](http://www.fortinet.com/products/fortigate/enterprise-firewalls.html)
- 2 маршрутизатора Cisco [ASR-1001](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-router/index.html)
- 2 маршрутизатора Cisco [ASR-1001-x](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-x-router/index.html)
- 6 коммутаторов административной сети Cisco [2960S-48TS-L](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-2960s-48ts-l-switch/model.html) (**1 на стойку** — 48 1Gbps портов + 4 SFP 1Gbps)
- 1 Dell [DMPU4032](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=A7546775) KVM
- 7 Dell [DAV2216](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=A7546777) агрегаторов KVM (**1–2 на стойку** — каждый соединяет с DPMU4032)

*Примечание: Каждый FEX имеет исходящую скорость связи со своим ядром 80 Gbps, а между ядрами предусмотрен канал порта на 160 Gbps. Поскольку денверский дата-центр возник позже, аппаратное обеспечение в нем чуть новее. Все  4 маршрутизатора — модели [ASR-1001-x](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-x-router/index.html), а 2 ядра — [Cisco Nexus 56128P](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/nexus-56128p-switch/index.html), имеющие 96 SFP+ портов на 10Gbps и 8 QSFP+ портов на 40Gbps каждый. Это позволяет выделить 10Gbps-порты для будущего расширения, поскольку мы можем связать ядра 4 связями по 40Gbps, вместо того, чтобы использовать 16 портов по 10Gbps, как это реализовано в Нью-Йорке.*

Так выглядит сетевое оборудование в Нью-Йорке:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

…и в Денвере:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Благодарить нужно [Марка Хендерсона](https://twitter.com/thefarseeker), одного из наших инженеров по вопросам надежности сайтов, который специально съездил в нью-йоркский дата-центр, чтобы сделать качественные фотографии к этой публикации.

#### SQL-сервера (кластер Stack Overflow)

- 2 сервера Dell [R720xd](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r720xd/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2697v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75283/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2697-v2-30M-Cache-2_70-GHz) (12 ядер по @2.7–3.5GHz)
- 384 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 1 Intel [P3608](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-dc-p3608-series.html) 4 TB NVMe PCIe SSD (RAID 0, по 2 контроллера на карту)
- 24 Intel [710](http://ark.intel.com/products/56584/Intel-SSD-710-Series-200GB-2_5in-SATA-3Gbs-25nm-MLC) 200 GB SATA SSD (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### SQL-сервера (кластер Stack Exchange «…и всего остального»)

- 2 сервера Dell [R730xd](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r730xd/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2667v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/83361/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2667-v3-20M-Cache-3_20-GHz)  (8 ядер по @3.2–3.6GHz)
- 768 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 32 GB)
- 3 Intel [P3700](http://ark.intel.com/products/79620/Intel-SSD-DC-P3700-Series-2_0TB-12-Height-PCIe-3_0-20nm-MLC) 2 TB NVMe PCIe SSD (RAID 0)
- 24 10K Spinny 1.2 TB SATA HDD (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

*Примечание: Аппаратное обеспечение SQL-серверов в Денвере по спецификациям идентично нью-йоркскому, но имеет только один SQL-сервер вместо двух, как в Нью-Йорке.*

Вот как выглядели SQL-сервера в Нью-Йорке во время апгрейда PCIe SSD upgrades в феврале:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Веб-сервера

- 11 серверов Dell [R630](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r630/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2690v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/81713/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2690-v3-30M-Cache-2_60-GHz) (12 ядер по @2.6–3.5GHz)
- 64 GB RAM (8 шт. DIMM по 8 GB)
- 2 Intel [320](http://ark.intel.com/products/56567/Intel-SSD-320-Series-300GB-2_5in-SATA-3Gbs-25nm-MLC) 300GB SATA SSD (RAID 1)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Сервисные сервера (рабочие)

- 2 сервера Dell [R630](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r630/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2643 v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/81900/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2643-v3-20M-Cache-3_40-GHz) (6 ядер по @3.4–3.7GHz)
- 64 GB RAM (8 шт. DIMM по 8 GB)
- 1 сервер Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd) со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2667](http://ark.intel.com/products/64589/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2667-15M-Cache-2_90-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) (6 ядер по @2.9–3.5GHz)
- 32 GB RAM (8 шт. DIMM по 4 GB)
- 2 Intel [320](http://ark.intel.com/products/56567/Intel-SSD-320-Series-300GB-2_5in-SATA-3Gbs-25nm-MLC) 300GB SATA SSD (RAID 1)
- Дублирующая сеть Dual 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

*Примечание: NY-SERVICE03 все еще R620, так как он недостаточно стар для замены. Он будет обновлен позже в этом году.*

#### Сервера Redis (кэш-память)

- 2 сервера Dell [R630](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r630/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2687W v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/81909/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2687W-v3-25M-Cache-3_10-GHz) (10 ядер по @3.1–3.5GHz)
- 256 GB RAM (16 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 2 Intel [520](http://ark.intel.com/products/66250/Intel-SSD-520-Series-240GB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-25nm-MLC) 240GB SATA SSD (RAID 1)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### Сервера Elasticsearch (поиск)

- 3 сервера Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2680](http://ark.intel.com/products/64583/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2680-20M-Cache-2_70-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) (8 ядер по @2.7–3.5GHz)
- 192 GB RAM (12 16 GB DIMM)
- 2 Intel [S3500](http://ark.intel.com/products/75685/Intel-SSD-DC-S3500-Series-800GB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-20nm-MLC) 800GB SATA SSD (RAID 1)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### Сервера HAProxy (балансировщики нагрузки)

- 2 сервера Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd) (CloudFlare Traffic), каждый со следующими параметрами:

  - Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2637 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/81900/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2643-v3-20M-Cache-3_40-GHz) (4 ядра по @3.5–3.8GHz)
  - 192 GB RAM (12 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
  - 6 Seagate [Constellation 7200RPM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HZEF2I) 1TB SATA HDD (RAID 10) (для системных журналов)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC) – внутренний трафик (DMZ)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540) – внешний трафик
- 2 сервера Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd) (прямой трафик), каждый со следующими параметрами:

  - Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2650](http://ark.intel.com/products/64590/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-20M-Cache-2_00-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) (8 ядер по @2.0–2.8GHz)
  - 64 GB RAM (4 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
  - 2 Seagate [Constellation 7200RPM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HZEF2I) 1TB SATA HDD (RAID 10) (для системных журналов)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC) – внутренний трафик (DMZ)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540) – внешний трафик

*Примечание: Эти сервера были заказаны в разное время и, как результат, различаются по спецификациям. Кроме того, два балансировщика нагрузки CloudFlare имеют больше памяти для установки memcached (который мы в данный момент не используем) для CloudFlare [Railgun](https://www.cloudflare.com/railgun/).*

Серверные боксы для упомянутых выше балансировщиков нагрузки, redis и поисковых серверов имеют высоту 1U для расположения в серверной стойке.

Вот как выглядит серверная стойка в Нью-Йорке:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Сервера для других задач

У нас есть и другие сервера, не связанные, прямо или косвенно, с обслуживанием трафика на сайтах. К этой задаче они либо имеют отдаленное отношение (например, контроллеры доменов, иногда используемые для проверки подлинности пула приложений и работающие как VM), либо предназначены для второстепенных задач, таких как мониторинг, хранение журналов, резервных копий и т. п.

Поскольку эта публикация задумывалась как приложение ко многим будущим публикациям [серии](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/), я также включаю в нее все интересные «фоновые» сервера.  Кроме того, это дает мне возможность поделиться с вами нашей серверной «клубничкой» — надеюсь, никто не против?..

#### VM-сервера (VMWare, в данный момент)

- 2 шасси лезвийных серверов Dell [FX2s](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-fx/pd), каждые 2 из 4 лезвий заполнены

  - 4 лезвийных сервера Dell [FC630](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-fx/pd#Misc) (по 2 на шасси), каждый со следующими параметрами:
  - Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2698](http://ark.intel.com/products/81900/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2643-v3-20M-Cache-3_40-GHz) v3 (16 ядер по @2.3–3.6GHz)
  - 768 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 32 GB)
  - 2 SD-карты по 16GB (Hypervisor  локально не хранится)
  - Дублирующая сеть 4х 10 Gbps (FX IOAs - BASET)
- 1 EqualLogic [PS6210](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/equallogic-ps6210-series/pd) iSCSI SAN

  - 24 шт. Dell 10K RPM 1.2TB SAS HDD (RAID10)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10Gb (10-BASET)
- 1 EqualLogic [PS6110](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/equallogic-ps6110/pd) iSCSI SAN

  - 24 шт. Dell 10K RPM 900GB SAS HDD (RAID10)
  - Дублирующая сеть 10Gb (SFP+)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Существует еще несколько незаметных, но достойных упоминания серверов, не являющихся VM. Они выполняют фоновые задачи, помогают нам отлаживать процесс ведения журнала, хранения резервных копий и т. п.

#### Сервера машинного самообучения (Providence)

Эти сервера находятся в режиме ожидания 99% времени, но во время ночной обработки, а именно – обновления Providence, испытывают серьезную нагрузку. Также они служат внутренним ресурсом для тестирования в рамках дата-центра новых алгоритмов на больших объемах данных.

- 2 сервера Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd) каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2697 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75283/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2697-v2-30M-Cache-2_70-GHz) (12 ядер по @2.7–3.5GHz)
- 384 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 4 Intel [530](http://ark.intel.com/products/75336/Intel-SSD-530-Series-480GB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-20nm-MLC) 480GB SATA SSDs (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### Redis-сервера машинного самообучения (также Providence)

Redis-хранилище данных для Providence. Стандартная установка включает один главный сервер, один ведомый сервер и один экземпляр, используемый для тестирования последних версий наших ML-алгоритмов. Эти данные, хотя и не используются для обслуживания сайтов вопросов и ответов, задействованы в обслуживании поиска вакансий на Careers и списков вакансий в боковой панели.

- 3 сервера Dell [R720xd](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r720xd/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2650 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75269/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-v2-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz) (8 ядер по @2.6–3.4GHz)
- 384 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 4 Samsung [840 Pro](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/products/flash-storage/client-ssd) 480 GB SATA SSD (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### Logstash-сервера (для журналов)

Наш кластер Logstash (использующий Elasticsearch для хранения) хранит всевозможные журналы. Мы хотим дублировать здесь http-журналы, но могут возникают проблемы с быстродействием. Как бы там ни было, здесь мы собираем все журналы  сетевых устройств, системные журналы, включая журналы систем Windows и Linux, чтобы наблюдать события в сети или быстро обнаружить возникшие проблемы.

Также используются как источник данных в Bosun для получения дополнительной информации в случае возникновения предупреждений. Общий объем хранилища в кластере – 6124 = 288 TB.

- 6 серверов Dell [R720xd](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r720xd/pd), каждый со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2660 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75272/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2660-v2-25M-Cache-2_20-GHz) (10 ядер по @2.2–3.0GHz)
- 192 GB RAM (12 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 12 шт. 7200 RPM Spinny 4 TB SATA
- HDD (RAID 0 x3 - 4 диска на шасси)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### SQL-сервер http-журналов

Именно здесь, в базе данных SQL, мы и храним информацию обо всех http–обращениях к нашим балансировщикам нагрузки (она отправляется с HAProxy через syslog).  Мы записываем лишь несколько высокоуровневых параметров:  URL, Query, UserAgent, временные параметры для SQL, Redis, и т. п. – все это ежедневно уходит в Clustered Columnstore Index. Мы используем этот сервер для отладки проблем пользователей, выявления бот-сетей и т. п.

- 1 сервер Dell [R730xd](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r730xd/pd) со следующими параметрами:
- Сдвоенные процессоры [E5-2660 v3](http://ark.intel.com/products/81706/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2660-v3-25M-Cache-2_60-GHz) (10 ядер по @2.6–3.3GHz)
- 256 GB RAM (16 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 2 Intel [P3600](http://ark.intel.com/products/80995/Intel-SSD-DC-P3600-Series-2_0TB-2_5in-PCIe-3_0-20nm-MLC) 2 TB NVMe PCIe SSD (RAID 0)
- 16 Seagate [ST6000NM0024](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/hdd/enterprise-capacity-3-5-hdd/?sku=ST6000NM0024) 7200RPM Spinny 6 TB SATA HDD (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

#### SQL-сервер разработчиков

Мы бы хотели, чтобы программисты при работе получали лучшую возможную производительность, и это касается SQL тоже… по крайней мере, так было в прошлом. Со времени последних закупок мы обновили рабочие процессоры. Мы собираемся добавить в этот бокс решение 2U – одновременно с тем, как будем обновлять кластер Stack Overflow позже в этом году.

- 1 сервер Dell [R620](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r620/pd) со следующими параметрами:
- Dual [E5-2620](http://ark.intel.com/products/64594/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-15M-Cache-2_00-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI) Processors (6 ядер по @2.0–2.5GHz each)
- 384 GB RAM (24 шт. DIMM по 16 GB)
- 8 Intel [S3700](http://ark.intel.com/products/71916/Intel-SSD-DC-S3700-Series-800GB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-25nm-MLC) 800 GB SATA SSDs (RAID 10)
- Дублирующая сеть 10 Gbps (Intel X540/I350 NDC)

Рассказ об аппаратном обеспечении, на котором работают сайты, и о том, что в этой связи может быть интересным, окончен. У нас, конечно, есть и другие сервера для фоновых задач типа ведения журналов, мониторинга, резервирования и т. д. Если вам очень интересно было бы получить спецификации решений для любых других систем, попросите об этом в комментариях, и я с радостью их предоставлю. Вот как все выглядело в сборке в нью-йоркском дата-центре несколько недель назад:

[image]

[image]

Что дальше? Темы для [публикаций этой серии](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/) подбираются в порядке убывания к ним интереса сообщества. Судя по популярности тем в [информационной панели Trello](https://trello.com/b/0zgQjktX/blog-post-queue-for-stack-overflow-topics), похоже, что следующая публикация будет посвящена [Внедрению](https://trello.com/c/bh4GZ30c/25-deployment). Поэтому в следующий раз вы узнаете, как код попадает из компьютера разработчика на рабочий сервер – и обо всем, что этому сопутствует. Я расскажу о миграциях баз данных, обновлениях программных версий, инфраструктуре CI, об организации нашей среды разработки, поделюсь статистикой о внедрении всего этого.

Comment: блог на моей мете? :-D

Comment: Это перевод. Мне показалось логичным оставить эту часть. Можно убрать, если считаете лишним.

Comment: Не :) понятно, что перевод. Просто не уверен, что мета==блог, этак тут сейчас начнутся разные:)

Comment: Хорошо, поправил. Спасибо за рекомендацию.

Comment: та не :-) я имел ввиду, может какой-то отдельный поддомен для таких переводов блогов?

Comment: По сути, это [публикация из блога компании](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/). Как мне кажется, лучшее место для подобных анонсов на нашей Мете. Я не вижу смысла создавать, к примеру, [коллективный блог](http://stackexchange.com/blogs), так как писать туда буду только я :)

Comment: мне кажется тут больше подошло бы добавление перевода именно в блог компании :) на том же ru поддомене

Comment: Первые предложения меня несколько озадачили ))

Comment: Предлагаю перенести информацию о переводе и авторе в самое начало. Тогда будет ясно, что я читаю и кто автор текста.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Готово!

Comment: @Grundy Блог копании на ru домене – это опять отдельный сайт, куда буду писать только я. С виду, что это неоправдано сложно по сравнению с публикацией на Мете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, но мне все еще кажется, что это было бы логичнее :)

Comment: кстати, а создавать отдельные под под домены ж не сложно? типа info.meta.ru.so... , и т.д.?

Comment: @Grundy Назначить поддомен – задача на минуту (просто новую запись в NS-сервера добавить).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а можно сделать, чтобы вопросы с меты помеченные какой-то определенной меткой автоматом показывали на своем под домене? типа [tag:информация] - info.meta.ru?

Comment: Интересно, а ажур или амазон или гугл не дешевле вышел бы?

Comment: Попиарил на ВК, посмотрим на трафик )) http://vk.com/iamdev?w=wall-80984752_3066

Comment: Ажур - точно не дешевле, сравнивал: их гигабайты RAM и гигагерцы CPU - совершенно нельзя сравнивать с характеристиками живых серверов, просто земля и небо. Т.е., вложения в живую инфраструктуру - дело конечно очень ответственное и затратное, но по крайней мере оправдывает свои ожидания.

Comment: Nicolas, благо дарю вам за перевод – мне очень увлекательно! Кстати, предыдущая статья есть **[тут](https://habr.com/company/ua-hosting/blog/278391/)**. У меня вопрос: после вашего этого перевода **[там вышло ещё 3 статьи](https://nickcraver.com/blog/archive/)**, их переводы тоже есть / будут?

Comment: Nicolas, и ещё вопрос: какие книги вы можете мне посоветовать почитать, чтобы мне научиться разбираться в том как собрать такое сооружение? Если знаете, конечно. И ещё: может у вас есть такая статья(-и) про ваш hashcode? Было бы увлекательно прочитать не только мне.

Comment: **[Перевод одной](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3139/297453)** из трёх следующих статей «How We Do Deployment - 2016 Edition». Может для них метку отдельную завести?