# Каким образом Stack Overflow зарабатывает в 2016 году

Tags: поддержка

<sub>Перевод публикации в блоге «[How We Make Money at Stack Overflow: 2016 Edition](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/How-We-Make-Money-at-Stack-Overflow-2016-Edition/)» [@NickCraver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)</sub>

Меня зовут Ник Кравер — вы, возможно, помните меня по публикациям о том, [как происходит развертывание на Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3139/), а также [какое железо мы используем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3037/).

Чего я еще не объяснил и что остается загадкой для большинства разработчиков, которых я встречаю — это то, как зарабатываем. Я хочу, наконец, остановиться на этом моменте. Не только потому, что часто слышу подобные вопросы, но и потому, что, по моему мнению, — и по мнению Stack Overflow, — абсолютная честность и прозрачность с сообществом пойдет всем только на пользу. Это также касается тем, на которые обычно не принято говорить (например, финансы) — по этой причине, например, мы создаем такие проекты как [калькулятор зарплат](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/salary-transparency/).

## Почему нам необходимо зарабатывать

Небольшое пояснение: на момент написания этой статьи я являюсь ведущим архитектором Stack Overflow. Я пишу статью после ежегодной встречи сотрудников нашей компании. Ежегодная встреча — очень значимое событие для сотрудников вроде меня, работающих удаленно:  я встречаюсь с людьми, которых никогда ранее не видел вживую, и обсуждаю с ними интересные идеи. Очень–очень много идей.

[image: Встреча работников]

Кроме прочего, мы вместе вспоминаем, почему мы делаем то, что делаем, и каких успехов можем добиться, работая в команде. Скоро исполняется 6 лет, с начала моей работы над, по моему мнению, лучшим ресурсом для разработчиков из всех возможных. И я рад, что с моей помощью он с каждым днем становится еще лучше. Но в этом процессе участвую не я один. Я невероятно благодарен возможности работать с нашими разработчиками, системными администраторами, дизайнерами, менеджерами, маркетологами, специалистами по продажам и всеми людьми со всего мира, которые нас поддерживают. Мы все создаем Stack Overflow.

[image: Еще одно фото встречи]

На прошлой неделе я очень долго беседовал с многими из этих людей (с некоторыми я говорил впервые) — мы обсуждали развитие нашей компании. Что еще более важно, мы пытались себе представить, как можно обеспечить стабильное развитие компании, если можно так выразиться, благими методами. Я придерживаюсь достаточно высоких стандартов в том, что касается нашего поведения, и надеюсь, что это отражается на вашем отношении к Stack Overflow. Спросите любого сотрудника – к нашим пользователям я отношусь супер-бережно. Я искренне верю, что нам удалось создать атмосферу взаимного уважения в сообществе, которой трудно добиться и которую ничем невозможно заменить. Я хочу работать в компании, которая уважает такое доверие – и я в ней работаю.

[image: Доверие]

Несмотря на то, что аналогичное мнение разделяют все сотрудники нашей компании, за время работы я не раз слышал сомнения, удастся ли нам совмещать уважение к пользователю и монетизацию, а также напоминания, что нам нужно как-то сводить концы с концами. Мы бы хотели развеять это заблуждение. Разумеется, деньги важны. Но основная наша цель – помогать людям: мы существуем, потому что вы позволяете нам существовать. Именно поэтому мы структурировали монетизацию в виде цикла, постоянно улучшающего сообщество, и не относимся к нашим продуктовым процессам, как к своего рода отвлечению ресурсов. То, сколько мы зарабатываем, напрямую зависит от того, насколько эффективно мы помогаем людям, вам – нашим пользователям. И чтобы дела наши шли хорошо, мы делаем все, чтобы оказываемая нами помощь была на высшем уровне. Пока это удавалось очень немногим компаниям, и мы гордимся, что входим в их число.

## Как мы зарабатываем

### Резюме и вакансии на Stack Overflow

Мы помогаем компаниям формировать бренд и набирать в штат технических специалистов с помощью наших продуктов – [доски объявлений и базы резюме](https://business.stackoverflow.com/). Эти услуги, в свою очередь, [помогают разработчикам найти лучшую работу](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) и ознакомиться с данными работодателей без применения агрессивных способов продвижения (спам-рассылка, рекламные баннеры и др.). Все, что мы делаем, мы анализируем с позиций удобства для разработчика – именно в этом состоит уникальность нашего маркетингового предложения.

Сервис трудоустройства во многом напоминает сервис вопросов и ответов, только компании ищут не ответ на вопрос, а разработчиков, а специалисты отвечают на их предложения.  И чтобы все это работало, нам нужны люди в обеих частях этого уравнения. Чем больше у нас есть работодателей и специалистов, тем быстрее и лучше мы помогаем разработчикам находить работу их мечты. В случае с работодателями мы стремимся к тому, чтобы обеспечить им выбор – пусть кандидатов будет немного, но они будут идеально соответствовать вакансии (это лучше, чем  предлагать выбор из 500 кандидатов, каждый из которых едва соответствует требованиям). Именно здесь мы можем предложить качественный сервис. Мы оптимизируем этот процесс. Мы не хотим, чтобы вы – или работодатели – зря теряли время: на сегодняшний день процесс трудоустройства еще настолько несовершенен, что мы планируем переработать его полностью.

[image: Вакансии]

Наша позиция достаточно оригинальна – мы одновременно можем помочь как работодателям, так и разработчикам. И это не пустые слова. Я верю в это. Я верю, что в этом мы можем значительно превзойти кого бы то ни было. Мы уже объединяем тысячи кандидатов и тысячи вакансий, но многие тысячи компаний все еще ждут кандидата. Один из шагов на пути улучшения этой ситуации – наша «[История разработчика](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/)». Я лично помогал создавать эту функциональность, потому что считаю ее значительным улучшением существующего формата резюме. Она помогает разработчикам в самопрезентации, в описании того, чем они занимаются, в доступной (я надеюсь) и технически осуществимой форме. А еще этот сервис помогает находить работу. Если вы находитесь в поиске, либо вас просто интересуют ваши шансы и перспективы, то чем полнее будет ваша История, тем выше вероятность того, что мы сможем найти для вас работу вашей мечты.

[image: Резюме против истории]

Если вам безразлично и то, и другое, не страшно. И хотя мы будем счастливы, если нам удается подобрать для вас работу вашей мечты, мы создавали раздел вакансий и раздел истории разработчика исключительно ради нашей основной миссии – обслуживания ВСЕХ разработчиков, включая тех из вас, кто в данный момент не обеспокоен вопросом трудоустройства. Мы работаем над тем, чтобы изменить отношение работодателей к разработчикам – и это выражается не только во встроенных стандартах раздела вакансий (например, отсутствие спама), но, например, еще и в политике [блога о найме разработчиков](https://business.stackoverflow.com/blog), который мы создали с единственной целью – улучшить стандартные процедуры, используемые работодателями и специалистами по подбору персонала. «История разработчика», в свою очередь, призвана изменить отношение к разработчикам, когда их личность отождествляется с их последним проектом или названием должности. Разработчики – творцы, им есть, что рассказать и как себя выразить: в коде, в публикациях блога, в принадлежности к определенной рабочей команде, и даже в том, что они в данный момент читают. Все наши продукты были созданы не для того, чтобы просто фигурировать на рынке, их цель – изменить парадигму.

### Реклама на Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow – очень большой сайт, и важную роль в поддержании его жизнеспособности играет [сервис рекламы](https://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise). Но мы не хотим тиражировать неактуальный или неинтересный контент. Мы будем давать вам только то, что вы хотите.

Наша цель – предоставление информации, которая бы могла считаться релевантной с человеческой точки зрения, и когда это нам не удается, мы стараемся дать вам информацию, релевантную по мнению нашего хитроумного компьютера. Не уверен, что предоставить компьютеру такую свободу действий было гениальным решением, но поживем-увидим. Как бы то ни было, мы постоянно над этим работаем. В наши обязанности входит создание таких рекламных объявлений (от которых, напоминаю, зависит существование нашего ресурса), которые были бы максимально пересекались с вашими интересами. Над этим у нас работают умнейшие люди, и бóльшая часть их работы состоит в одном: понять разработчиков, чтобы лучше обслуживать их интересы.

(Как мы относимся к блокировке рекламы? Безразлично – [и вот почему](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/).)

Какова наша рекламная политика в данный момент? Вкратце, мы не наращиваем ее объемы, мы улучшаем то, что уже имеется. Мы лучше, чем многие другие ресурсы, [разбираемся](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) в том, какие технологии вы, как разработчики, предпочитаете. И мы хотели бы сформировать видение того, что можно придумать, чтобы сделать рекламу максимально актуальной и релевантной. Это займет чуть больше времени, но мы также хотим ускорить загрузку рекламных объявлений (это еще один наш проект, более крупный).

Чего мы делать не собираемся – так это снижать качество нашей рекламы. Знаете ли вы, что ежемесячно на Stack Overflow публикуется огромное количество бесплатных материалов? Каждый раз, когда вы видите надпись "house ad" (так мы называем рекламные объявления других сайтов нашей сети) или "community ad" ([за которую голосует сообщество](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327559/open-source-advertising-2h-2016)), помните, что на этом месте могла бы быть платная реклама. Но ее нет. Потому что если у нас нет чего-нибудь как–либо вам полезного, мы этого вам не покажем.

Также мы не хотели бы использовать какую-либо систему автоматического  отбора рекламы, которая будет это делать вместо нас. Мы уже это рассматривали. Это не позволяло нам достичь того уровня  качества, которое мы хотели бы поддерживать. Мы сознательно отказались от большой доли прибыли. Компромиссы в вопросах качества не для нас. Мы пойдем другим путем.

Важно понимать, что мысль отказаться от рекламы зародилась в нашей команде по продаже рекламы. Эти люди зарабатывают непосредственно на продаже рекламы, тем не менее, инициатива исходила именно от них, потому что их больше заботит наше дело, и то, что вы о нас думаете, а не личная выгода. Вы себе не представляете, как редко такое бывает! Наш отдел помощи подбора персонала, который общается с работодателями, имеет аналогичное мнение. Все эти люди ставят дело выше личных интересов – именно поэтому мне так нравится работать в нашей компании.

Некоторые из наших рекламных объявлений подгружаются медленно (спасибо участникам Меты за предоставленные отчеты!). Мы отслеживаем таких рекламодателей и по мере сил помогаем им разобраться в причинах. Это сложная история, учитывая, сколько людей задействовано, но мы продолжаем над этим работать. Мой коллега Само и я будем проставлять временные метки для этих задач, чтобы в будущем не упускать их из виду и получать автоматические уведомления в случае возникновения проблем. Мы считаем, что реклама, которая медленно загружается, портит общее впечатление пользователя от сервиса. Производительность – это «фича», и все, что происходит на странице, имеет для нас огромное значение.

Я работаю с нашей командой по продаже рекламы, чтобы начиная с января 2017 года все наши рекламные объявления были совместимы с протоколом HTTPS. В данный момент совместимость в большинстве случаев возможна, но не гарантируется, но в будущем мы решим этот вопрос. Я не хочу, чтобы это кому-либо мешало. Мы собираемся переместить все изображения с сайта Imgur на https://, и мы это осуществим. Кроме того, я хочу перенести на https:// все логотипы и пиктограммы сайта. Мы работаем над этим очень крупным проектом… но это повод для совсем другой (очень длинной) публикации.

### Сервис вопросов и ответов для компаний: Stack Overflow Enterprise

Мы собираемся уделить больше времени развитию [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://business.stackoverflow.com/enterprise). Сайт начинает раскручиваться: это еще один сервис, с помощью которого  мы можем помочь разработчикам (как тем, кто сидит за корпоративными брандмауэрами, так и тем, кто работает непосредственно у нас). Этой задачей у нас загружены несколько постоянных сотрудников. Корпоративные среды – явление уникальное и относиться к нему надо с особой любовью.

Однако Enterprise использует ту же систему контроля версий, что и stackoverflow.com – ту же самую ветку git. Иногда функциональность Enterprise пересекается с функциональностью stackoverflow.com. Например, мы планируем настроить для HTTPS простой прокси-сервер изображений, который мог бы служить сервером изображений внутри брандмауэра Enterprise.  Помните, чуть выше я писал о публикациях участников о скорости загрузки? Они помогут нам определить необходимую пропускную способность. Все, что мы делаем – частички одного пазла.

## Доверие

Процесс монетизации в компании наших масштабов невозможен без значительных маркетинговых усилий.

Еще два года тому назад я не доверял нашей маркетинговой команде. Почему? Потому что она была только что создана, и я не знал всех этих людей. Но я был знаком с другими маркетологами и имел отрицательный опыт общения с ними. Поэтому по умолчанию я думал так: «хороших маркетологов не бывает, они все готовы играть на доверии пользователя ради быстрого результата». Оказывается, что это не так. Не у нас. Мне пришлось работать с нашими маркетологами в нескольких проектах, чтобы преодолеть это предубеждение и понять простую истину: мы наняли потрясающих маркетологов, которых беспокоят те же вопросы, что и меня. Кейтлин, тебе особая благодарность! Нашей команде маркетологов пришлось столкнуться с огромным сопротивлением со стороны разработчиков, и они перенесли это безропотно. Они доказали нам ценность своих предложений и смогли убедить умнейших из тех, кого я знаю, во множестве принципиальных вещей.

Все наши команды знают, что сообщество Stack Overflow и доверие этого сообщества – самый ценный из имеющихся у нас ресурсов. Мы хотим общаться, а не враждовать. И мы считаем, что это возможно только взаимными усилиями. Да, если правильно к этому подойти, некоторые вещи будут полезны и нам как компании. Я не считаю это зазорным. Если мы сможем развивать компанию, мы сможем дать миру больше удивительных находок. У меня в запасе столько идей, столько проектов, которые я хочу для вас реализовать! Спросите меня хотя бы о переносе Stack Overflow на сервер 2U в Европе, Азии и Южной Америке, скорость которого кое-где превышает скорость света.

Я видел презентацию Адрианны ([нашего директора по маркетингу](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/05/Welcoming-Stack-Overflows-New-CMO-Adrianna-Burrows/), она работает с нами сравнительно недавно), которая меня поразила до глубины души. На самом деле, до ее выступления на нашей встрече я с ней не сталкивался, но первое впечатление она на меня произвела потрясающее. Во время ее презентации я постоянно думал: почему мы не сделали вот это вот все четыре года назад?..

[image: Разработка, продажи и маркетинг на Stack Overflow]

Маркетинг, как и разработка, состоит по большей части в сопоставлении фактов и выявлении взаимосвязей. Мое прежде безрадостное общение с «маркетологами» превратилось в чистое удовольствие. У нас работают умные люди с честными намерениями, которые всегда придут на помощь. Честно, я поражен.

### Небольшой пример того, как мы завоевываем ваше доверие: почтовые рассылки

Доверие друг к другу и общие ценности относительно способов заработка напрямую связаны с тем, как мы выстраиваем внутренние инструменты. Приведу вам самый первый пример, который приходит на ум, подтверждающий, что доверие – необходимая составляющая всех наших продуктов:

Так что я там возглавляю – команду архитекторов? Наша команда писала новую почтовую систему для постоянного общения с нашими пользователями (нам много помогали). Почему я об этом рассказываю? Потому что сам прошел путь от ярого противника создания подобного функционала до члена команды. Кстати, в нашей команде только я и Само Прелог. «Команда» – это слишком громкое слово. Но как нас назвать – парой? На самом деле, просто два разработчика создали «Лигу справедливости» в миниатюре… Ладно, вернемся к нашему почтовому сервису.

Что первое я внес в спецификацию? Возможность отписки. Это первое, что мы реализовали. Это однозначно самая важная для нас функциональность. Отписка в один клик и специальная страница, на которой вы можете настроить подписку – это не обсуждалось. Первый приоритет. Несколько лет назад я удалил аккаунт в LinkedIn из-за спама. Если вы не хотите получать наши сообщения – не проблема. Я приношу свои извинения, если первое время мы присылали вам письма без вашего разрешения, и буду благодарен за ваше понимание наших мотивов. Одно из моих величайших опасений – мысль о том, что наше поведение может раздражать сообщество. Такие мысли не дают мне спать по ночам.

Сейчас мы готовим рассылку с анонсом «Истории разработчика», адресованную более широкому количеству пользователей в надежде, что сервис поможет большему числу разработчиков. Если вы откажетесь от его получения, мы вас отпишем. Если вы не будете отвечать на наши сообщения, мы вас отпишем. Если вы пометите письма как спам, мы тоже вас отпишем. Это критично для нас. Каждое новое сообщение, кроме служебных (например, восстановление доступа), отправленных нашей системой, будет иметь три ссылки внизу сообщения: ссылка, позволяющая отписаться в один клик, прямая ссылка доступа ко всем категориям и ссылка отправки обратной связи.

Одна из причин, почему мы создаем нашу систему именно в таком виде (а это требует ощутимо больших трудозатрат), состоит в том, что если текущий провайдер не будет справляться (в данный момент мы используем SendGrid, пока полет нормальный!), мы можем быть уверены, что ваши просьбы об отписке будут обрабатываться корректно. Мы не хотим рисковать, надоедая пользователям, которые ясно выразили свое желание отписаться.

И хотя в данный момент мы имеем только одну категорию ("New Features"), мы планируем добавить еще. О добавлении новых видов рассылки речи не идет. Мы хотим перенести в новую систему все существующие рассылки, например, [бюллетень сообщества](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) (если вы с ней не сталкивались – возможность отписаться в ней предусмотрена), чтобы вы могли легко и просто им управлять, отписываясь в один клик. В данный момент наша страница настроек получения почтовых уведомлений, честно говоря, никуда не годится.

Это устаревший артефакт, оставшийся со времен первой версии сайта, который нужно переделывать. Над этим у нас кое-кто уже работает. Одна из наших дизайнеров, Донна, делает все возможное, чтобы максимально упростить систему. Необходимо сделать массу изменений в коде, чтобы поддержать такую унификацию и упрощение. Надеемся, мы сможем создать систему, содержащую всего одно место для указания вашего почтового адреса, где вы сможете конфигурировать все настройки почты, приходящей со Stack Overflow. Если они будут вас раздражать, полная отписка потребует от вас (самое большее) 1-2 клика.

Вся коммуникация и наше с вами взаимодействие должно отражать наше уважение к вам. Если это не так, мы не оправдали ваших – и своих – надежд. Наша миссия – улучшать жизнь разработчиков. Когда я не могу уснуть, такие мысли часто меня беспокоят. Мы должны быть достойны вашего доверия, мы должны его завоевывать.

Если позже мы добавим новые категории рассылок (а не просто разобьем на категории существующие), подписанные пользователи не будут иметь возможность выразить свое согласие на получение рассылки – по умолчанию, она будет предоставляться только новым пользователям. Мы не хотели бы чтобы про наши сообщения говорили «ах, это опять с того сайта». Серьезно. Мы намеренно стараемся избежать подобного.

Если вы прочтете анонс нашей Истории разработчика и не захотите больше получать подобное – никаких проблем. Надеюсь, Stack Overflow сможет помочь вам в другом, и я благодарю вас за то, что уделили нам время. Думаю, наша [документация](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) и постоянно улучшаемый раздел вопросов и ответов упростят вашу жизнь. Это истинная цель работы компании. И моей тоже.

## Что дальше: наши мысли о будущем

У меня огромное количество новых идей! Я хочу развернуть базу данных временных рядов на SQL Server в Clustered Columnstore. Хочу проверить идею, возникшую у нас как-то в полночь по совершенствованию подачи новостей для разработчиков. Хочу установить несколько информационных соединений (эта задача почти завершена) для наших внутренних команд, что позволит им добиться экономии времени. Передо мной тысяча дел!

И, честно признаюсь, я нахожусь в радостном возбуждении. По поводу будущего нашей документации. По поводу историй разработчиков.  Все это меня необыкновенно вдохновляет. Я хочу, чтобы финансовые вопросы существования компании нас не отвлекали, и мы могли свободно реализовать все, что может принести ощутимую пользу нашим сообществам. Я знаю, что мы этого добьемся, и с обоюдной пользой. Надеюсь, то, что я здесь написал, поможет понять, что происходит внутри Stack Overflow – хотя бы немного, хотя бы мне самому. Если вы с чем-то не согласны – это ваше право. Но если у вас есть время, я был бы благодарен вам, если бы вы рассказали мне в комментариях, почему, чтобы я/мы могли это улучшить.

Благодарю вас за внимание.

Ник Кравер, главный архитектор

Comment: Спасибо, Ник, за статью!

Comment: Собственно, всю статью можно ужать до одной фразы: мы зарабатываем с помощью рекламы вакансий.

Comment: было бы неплохо еще опубликовать статью как создавался SO

Comment: Интересно, а наш руСО прибыльный или нет?

Comment: @Cerbo Нет. На Stack Overflow на русском нет платных сервисов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но кое у кого есть ЗАРплатный сервис :)