# За счет чего живет сайт stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка

Не придумал, по каким меткам задать подобный вопрос и куда.

Очевидно, сайт посещает куча народу и для этого нужны хорошие мощности. Для поддержки и администрирование нужна группа разработчиков. Но на сайте нет ни одной рекламы (выключил все блокировщики, какие нашел у себя).

Внимание вопрос: за счет чего живут подобные сайты? За счет бизнес-ангелов? Откуда у сайта средства за жизнь? Да, у них есть комьюнити. Да, у них есть контент. Но за счет чего живет этот сайт и подобные им (не имея рекламу и платные плюшки)

Comment: Всё есть. Просто stackoverflow несколько шире, чем вы его себе представляете.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Там целый [пост](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/15/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition) про это был. Ещё есть [ответ от Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79448/260198).

- Реклама.
- Инвестиции.
- Партнёрки с компаниями. Вы видели на en SO иконки на некоторых метках? Вот за это компании платят деньги.
- [Stackoverflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise).
- [Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/get-started).

**UPD:** оказывается у нас и перевод есть: [Каким образом Stack Overflow зарабатывает в 2016 году](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4146/15479)

Comment: Ссылка на перевод как раз предлагается как оригинал закрытия дубликатом.

Comment: @alexolut спросонья не заметил )=

Answer (score 5):

Вот что написано в википедии по этому вопросу:

> Stack Exchange получал инвестиции от Union Square Ventures (6 млн
>   долларов, 2010), Index Ventures (12 млн, 2011), Bezos Expeditions (10
>   млн, 2013), Andreessen Horowitz и другие (40 млн, 2014)[9]. Всего на
>   начало 2015 года было получено 70 млн инвестиций, однако сеть так и не
>   стала прибыльной[10].
>
> Для монетизации используется онлайн-реклама на сайтах сети (количество
>   рекламы уменьшается для пользователей, набравших определенный уровень
>   репутации), от неё сайт получает около трети выручки. Также в рамках
>   сети развивается коммерческий портал для поиска работы и работников
>   Stack Overflow Careers[10][11]. Ранее сеть также предоставляла
>   собственные технологии как платный сервис, позволяя сторонним
>   компаниям легко создавать сайты вопросов и ответов.