# Как сильно увеличивается StackOverflow на русском каждый месяц?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, статистика

Это, наверное, будет мой самый длинный вопрос, который я задаю. Перед тем как задавать этот вопрос я поискал предварительно интересующую меня тему на "мете", если все-таки я где-то пропустил подобный вопрос, то буду рад, если укажите мне на дублирующий вопрос.

Начал задавать вопросы на этом форуме я довольно недавно по сравнению с остальными участниками. Несмотря на критику, минуса и прочие воспитательные моменты связанные с моими вопросами, я очень благодарен всем, кто хоть как-то приложил свою руку или руки к моему развитию. Дело в том, что я на данный момент занимаюсь Android-разработкой и так как я много чего не знаю, потому что я начинающий, то соответственно задаю вопросы здесь.

На StackOverflow Meta я вообще только начал задавать вопросы, и чем мне нравится эта часть огроменной сети, так это тем, что здесь можно узнать очень много как про саму сеть, так и про интересующую тебя тему (например, я узнал какое железо юзает сеть — [Stack Overflow: Аппаратное обеспечение 2016](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3037/stack-overflow-%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2016), статья, конечно, старая, но тем не менее мне было очень интересно почитать).

Данный вопрос я не знаю, если честно, кому именно адресовать, основателям, модераторам или простым пользователям. Мне стало интересно как сильно увеличивается количество вопросов на форуме, за какой-то период ( месяц или год например). Сейчас я увидел что всего на Stack Overflow на русском 227,910 вопросов, а задающих-отвечающих по-моему, если я не ошибаюсь, чуть больше 100,000.

На текущий момент, на форуме действует довольно строгая система пропуска вопросов, и если бы не модераторы, то сервера сети раздуло бы)) Каждую неделю я задаю вопросы которые мне не понятны, и которые я хочу решить для себя и своих задач. У меня количество вопросов постоянно растет, вероятнее всего из-за того что я много чего не знаю. И я не один такой необразованный, нас много!!!

Я думаю что вначале, система контроля количества вопросов была примитивной, но после определенного периода работы, создатели и основатели увидели что количество вопросов неконтролируется и многие из них можно, например, удалить.

Если я запрашиваю какую-то закрытую и секретную информацию, то можете удалить мой вопрос.

P.S. Дорогие модераторы, я долго думал какие метки выбрать для этого вопроса, поэтому если что-то не то выбрал, или чего-то не выбрал то буду рад если поможете (эту запись после редактирования вопроса можно удалить).

Comment: Ещё было бы интересно как-то соотнести количество с качеством (:

Comment: ну это да)) эти два параметра не всегда одинаковы)

Comment: Эти данные надо у КМ запросить. Когда вернётся с отпуска, конечно.

Comment: а кто такой КМ?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Всея Комьюнити Менеджер SE. Николас.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7399/218063 Ссылка по теме: https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday

Comment: `Сервера сети раздуло бы` - мало что в интернете сегодня удаляется по настоящему. Вопросы на SO не исключение. Они не удаляются, они просто скрываются.

Comment: то есть они все-равно там висят? и их намного больше получается чем 220к?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko 298290 вместе с удаленными: http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/893574

Comment: Меня больше волнует бардак в вопросах. Мало того, что большинство людей задают вопросы без нормального форматирования, такие, что их приходится править, так они еще и формулируют их так, что их нельзя найти в гугле. И если у такого же человека появится такой же вопрос, и он не найдет его в гугле, то он пойдет на СО и задаст свой вопрос(возможно тоже ужасно написанный). Его конечно же пометят как дубликат, но он все равно останется в сети SO. И таких людей сотни. Получается бардак.

Comment: P.S.И вообще, надо бы сделать сайт, с интерфейсом гугла(работающий как поиск ответов-вопросов на главной), но без возможности задать вопрос, что-бы новые участники сначала искали ответ на вопрос, а не задавали бы 100500 похожий вопрос.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, полностью с вами согласен. Когда я только начинал задавать здесь вопросы, я даже не пробовал их сначала поискать, и вот только спустя некоторое время, я вначале делаю поиск во всех доступных мне источниках, и только потом уже задаю свой вопрос. Когда человек только приходит на СО, он не всегда правильно формулирует не только название вопроса, но и тело вопроса, и как результат глупые обиды на модераторов и остальных пользователей, которые указывают на ошибки. Я это сужу по своему личному опыту))

Comment: @AntonSorokin такой сайт уже существует - google :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы)). Просто хочется как-то упорядочить все вопросы-ответы, а сейчас такое ощущение, что все в куче. Может есть способ вынести все более менее уникальные вопросы куда-нибудь? Уникальные - не те, где просят помочь с кодом, что-то написать, подсказать(т.е., которые почти не могут помочь другим). Это вопросы по типу: чем отличается, в чем плюсы, что такое, и т.п.
А, еще вопросы про ошибки, связанные и с кодом, и с другими вещами, например с intellij(т.е., которые помогут всем). 
Вообще, я сужу по поиску. Если у меня проблема, то я иду в гугл. Если мне идет ссылка на SO -

Comment: - то значит, что вопрос хороший.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я вот не знал если честно, что на SO есть возможность самостоятельно слать запросы в БД. [вот мой запрос](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/893870#resultSets). Я думаю, что теперь не обязательно тревожить КМ, потому-что путем несложных вычислений можно посчитать сколько прирост вопросов за неделю, месяц и год. Все зависит от запроса.

Спасибо, что показали этот механизм.

Comment: У КМ куда больше инструментов и статистики. Та же гугл-аналитика, там даже запросы составлять не надо :)

Comment: не ну если так, то конечно ему вообще все очень просто посмотреть)) но тем не менее такой простой пользователь, как я может спокойно, используя представленный инструмент, посмотреть и посчитать все самостоятельно)

Comment: @Other гугл аналитика открывается всем, кто 25к репы наберёт.

Comment: @Suvitruf, мне до 25к еще очень далеко)) предложенный мне инструмент дает небольшой доступ к информации, так-что чем богаты тем и рады :)

Comment: @Suvitruf Не полная аналитика, да и у ТС нет 25k для просмотра, смекаешь?

Comment: @Other немного напрячься и будет 25к)

Comment: @Suvitruf Плохой мотиватор. Вот если бы после 25k выдавали купон в публичный дом - мигом наотвечали бы!

Comment: @Other, тут я с вами соглашусь, если бы выдавали купоны, то количество людей с реп. 25к + резко увеличилось)) но к сожалению выдача купонов это из разряда фантастики :))

Answer (score 8):

В день задается порядка 200 вопросов

http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/893870#resultSets

Comment: это уже с учетом всех удаленных? или это общее количество?

Comment: Это то, что осталось после удаления вопросов